# How do you programmatically assign value to a WHERE clause parameter in EntityDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I realised a Parameter object does not have a Value property, so how do you assign a value to a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the DefaultValue property, like so:

```
edsGrantsList.WhereParameters["FileToken"].DefaultValue = txtToken.Text
```

In this example, my EntityDataSource is called edsGrantsList and it has a where parameter that is defined like this:

```
<WhereParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="FileToken" Type="String" DefaultValue="" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
</WhereParameters>
```